# React Native/ Any Npm is there for drag and drop match component?

Tags: react-native, expo

[image]

```
I want to drag and drop image left to right section if it is matched the function will call otherwise if it is not matched the another function will call
```

React native component drag and drop with function

Comment: How did you manage this?

Answer (score 1):

Try [react-native-drax](https://github.com/nuclearpasta/react-native-drax). You can also [listen to a podcast](https://devchat.tv/react-native-radio/rnr-155-react-native-drax-and-open-source-with-joe-lafiosca/) with the creator of this library.